# Two way composition a good design to establish communication between objects of two different classes?

Tags: oop, composition

Is it a good OOD practice to have a class that has a reference to another class(Composition) which inturn has a reference to the same class?

**ClassA ----->ClassB   and ClassB ----->ClassA ??**

By having this sort of relationship, I can make changes to the states of object class A from B and vice versa. Is this a good design pattern to establish communication between objects or is there a different preferred approach to this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a relationship is a cyclic dependency. Per se, it has only disadvantages. It can stop many garbage collectors dead in their tracks. Releasing the objects requires negotiation between clients of both A and B because all clients of A are also inherently clients of B, and vice versa.

Given such interdependencies, you should probably introduce another object which manages the collection of interdependent objects. The clients can all negotiate with the manager to decide when everything is finished and resources can be released.

To avoid the problem, pass references to objects contextually as function arguments (or similar transient, local state) instead of using persistent members.